# AVFoundation Image Capture signal SIGBART error

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am getting a `signal SIGBART` error when trying to capture an image using AVFoundation. It is supposed to take the image automatically without bringing up any views, the idea is to capture a slightly unflattering image.

```
func captureImage() {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    }

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    for device in devices as! [AVCaptureDevice] {
        if device.position == .front {
            let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                self.beginSession(stillImageOutput: stillImageOutput)
            }
        }
    }
}

func beginSession(stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput) {
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
            let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
            self.profileImage.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)


            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.profileImage.image!, nil, nil, nil)

        })
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the first and second line of the beginSession function. It also says `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

I've never done anything like this so it's probably something basic. Any help would be great. Thanks